# Selbstenthüllung, Selbstdarstellung und Selbstoffenbarung

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich habe in Wörterbüchern nach der Bedeutung von *Selbstenthüllung* gesucht, leider habe ich nichts gefunden.

Könnte mir jemand in Bezug auf eine anerkannte Quelle dieses Wort erklären bzw. konkrete Beispiel-Formulierungen geben.

Ich würde gerne wissen, wie Selbstenthüllung im Zusammenhang mit Selbstdarstellung und Selbstoffenbarung steht.

Comment: Willkommen auf dem Stack Exchange für die Deutsche Sprache. Kannst Du bitte Deine Frage [edit]ieren, um Folgendes zu beantworten: In welchem Kontext bist Du auf dieses Wort gestoßen? Was hast Du bis jetzt herausgefunden und verstanden und was ist unkar?

Comment: *Enthüllung* meint die öffentliche Erstvorführung eines Kunstwerkes. *Enthüllungsartikel* und *Enthüllungsbuch* sind hingegen journalistische Arbeiten, die etwas zuvor Geheimes der Öffentlichkeit zugänglich machen, also quasi "enthüllen". Eine "Selbstenthüllung" sollte also ebenso etwas Verborgenes der Öffentlichkeit sichtbar machen, ausgehend aber von dem Verbergenden selbst.

Answer (score 1):

Selbstenthüllung kommt in den psychoanalytische Literatur vor in dem Sinn von „self-disclosure“. zB - situationsangemessene Selfstenthüllung, exhibitionistische Selfstenthüllung, normgerecthe Selfstenthüllung, usw.

„In der Psychoanalyse ist Selbstenthullung der erste Schritt zu Selbsterkenntnis“

"Authentizität rechtfertigt Selbstenthüllung."

Answer (score 0):

Das Wort "Selbstenthüllung" kommt im Duden gar nicht vor und ist mir auch noch nie begegnet.
Selbstdarstellung bezeichnet die Tätigkeit und Absicht, Anderen ein (häufig übertriebenes oder falsches) positives Bild von sich selbst zu vermitteln.
Selbstoffenbarung bezeichnet die Tätigkeit, etwas Geheimes über sich preiszugeben.